# Why is this producing an "Empty Path Name Is Not Legal" exception?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I'm attempting to use BinaryFormatter to serialize the state of a program I'm developing, but I'm getting the following error when I attempt to Deserialize the resulting file. My code checks to make sure the File Name is valid (Already added that after seeing a lot of Similar Questions here), so I'm not understanding how this error is happening:

> System.ArgumentException
>   Message=Empty path name is not legal.
>   Source=mscorlib
>   StackTrace:
>   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
>   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
>   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.SetupDecoderFromUriOrStream(Uri uri, Stream stream, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, Guid& clsId, Boolean& isOriginalWritable, Stream& uriStream, UnmanagedMemoryStream& unmanagedMemoryStream, SafeFileHandle& safeFilehandle)
>   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateFromUriOrStream(Uri baseUri, Uri uri, Stream stream, BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, RequestCachePolicy uriCachePolicy, Boolean insertInDecoderCache)
>   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage.FinalizeCreation()
>   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage.EndInit()
>   at StarShips.Ship..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt) in C:\Projects\Dalek\StarShips\Ship.cs:line 387

Here's my Save method, which is creating the file initially:

```
Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog sfd = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
sfd.FileName = "NewGame";
sfd.DefaultExt = ".sav";
sfd.Filter = "Save Games (.sav)|*.sav";
Nullable<bool> result = sfd.ShowDialog();
if (result == true)
{
    string fileName = sfd.FileName;
    IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    Stream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
    GameTest t = new GameTest();
    t.Players = GameState.Players;
    formatter.Serialize(stream, t);

    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Save Complete! Size: {0}",stream.Length));
    stream.Close();
}
```

And here's the code that is throwing the exception:

```
Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog ofd = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
ofd.FileName = "NewGame";
ofd.DefaultExt = ".sav";
ofd.Filter = "Save Games (.sav)|*.sav";
Nullable<bool> result = ofd.ShowDialog();
if (result == true)
{
    string fileName = ofd.FileName;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(fileName);
    IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    Stream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
    stream.Position = 0;
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("size: {0}, Filename: {1}", stream.Length,((FileStream)stream).Name));
    GameTest t = (GameTest)formatter.Deserialize(stream); // Error occurs here
    stream.Close();
}
```

I've tried saving/loading to/from nearly everywhere in my file-system, from the root of the C drive and even in the execution folder for the program.
I've tried stepping into the Deserialize, and it iterates through a ton of the object graph, but then suddenly kicks back to my Deserialize call above and throws the exception.
The messagebox just before my deserialization shows that the filename for the stream is valid, so why am I getting this message?

**EDIT:** If I continue past the error while debugging, I get another error: "End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed." I double checked through all of my classes, and all of the GetObjectData methods add the same values the Serialization constructors, so I don't know where it's running beyond the stream.

Comment: You have the file name, but where is the actual path?

Comment: FileName includes the full path, e.g. "C:\NewGame.sav".  To my knowledge this is how the MSDN article for Basic Serialization handles this as well, and the de-serialization gets through most of the object graph before throwing the error.

Comment: Why are you using the Win32.OpenFileDialog and not Forms.OpenFileDialog?  Maybe there's some incompatibility in the path returned?

Comment: @jcyost: this is in a WPF app, honestly I was just following the tutorial I googled up.

Comment: @aw04 the Filename always includes the full path to wherever I load the file from, so I'm not sure if setting the InitialDirectory on the OpenFileDialog would affect the BinaryFormatter.Deserialize method.

Comment: Try setting ofd.CheckPathExists = true.  What happens?

Comment: @jcyost No change from that, but editing the question now: Continuing past the current error gets to an "End of Stream encountered before parsing was complete" error.

Comment: Just a few more random thoughts... Is there a reason you're setting the stream position?  By default it should start at the beginning of the stream.  And maybe try setting FileShare.None in case Explorer is interfering.  And finally I'd replace IFormatter with BinaryFormatter in the event that the BinaryFormatter class behaves differently.  Aside from that, I can't see any issues.

Comment: You did not post the correct code, it is not complaining at all about the code you've posted.  It is a bug in your Ship class constructor, it tries to create a bitmap even though the filename for it is an empty string.  Why it does this, or why the filename is empty, is not guessable.  Use the debugger.

Comment: @HansPassant Brilliant! That was the exact problem, the Ship constructor was trying to init a BitmapImage based on a URI value that hadn't been deserialized yet (I moved the init into the property's getter for a lazy-load and everything works great). _How_ did you get that from what I've posted?

Comment: @DavidCEllis He got it from looking at the call stack (the "StackTrace") which you posted: the details in the exception message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> at StarShips.Ship..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)

The call stack of the exception shows that you are looking the completely wrong corner for this problem.  You assumed it is the path of the file that contains the serialized data that is wrong, the stack trace tells a very different story.

In case it is confusing, `.ctor` is the internal CLR name for the constructor of a class.  So it is actually your Ship class constructor that bombs.  It tries to create a BitmapImage object with the BitmapImage(Uri) constructor.  It is the argument to that constructor that has the problem.  Probably because you forgot to serialize the filename of the bitmap or not correctly dealing with this string being null or empty.

Put a breakpoint on the Ship constructor to single-step the code.  Or use Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown checkbox for CLR exceptions so that the debugger stops when the exception is thrown.  Or remove the try/catch in your code that swallows the exception, it is getting in the way of diagnosing problems.

Comment: Aha! I was focusing on the top and missed that part. Note to self: read the entire stack trace next time.